# How to I create Jira tickets for broken Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I want to automate the creation of Jira tickets for each broken pipeline build in Jenkins.

How can I do this? Does anyone has a working groovy example to to use inside `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: There's [an open request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40090) for adding this functionality to Jenkins jira-plugin.

Comment: @PasiH maybe it would worth making this an answer.

Comment: I would but the question has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution can be wrapping all sensitive steps in try-catch. And use Jira [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) for creating of a new tickets.